# Excel 2010 chart - possible to draw ellipse around charted points?

Tags: excel, vba

I have no idea how to approach this problem so any pointers are appreciated. We have Lat & Long points charted in Excel 2010 in a standard X-Y plot.  For each data point coordinate we have additional data defining an ellipse of error associated with that data point (major axis, minor axis, and angle). The ellipse represents a search area. Is it feasible to draw the ellipse around each data point?  We have all the data and can chart the x-y points OK, but clueless on how to draw the ellipses in Excel/VBA or if it's even possible.  Many thanks.  Have searched without success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing chart type that would give you that type of output, so you will probably need to draw the chart yourself with some rather painful VBA (if you have to do it in VBA in the first place... C# might be better).

Start by taking a look at the [Shapes.AddShape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821384.aspx) method to see how you can draw the error ellipse you need for each point. Then think about the chart itself.

```
Sub DrawOval()
    Set myDocument = Worksheets(1)
    myDocument.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeOval, 50, 50, 100, 200
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can define the ellipse you need, you can calculate points around the circumference of the ellipse, then plot these points as an additonal XY scatter series in the chart.